# updating list as new options are selected - html/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say there's a list A = [1,2,3,4,5]

The user can choose one or more options (this is done through a multiselect dropdown)

On the side screen, I want to display (html) the options that the user has chosen and the list should update as the user selects or deselects options from the multiselect.

How do I get the html to "update" to do this? Making the list appear is easy, just get the selected options with js and then:

```
    document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = selectedlist.join("<br>");
```

but, the printed list naturally does not update as I select or deselect options.

Any tips would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You will want to use the select box's `change` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting full list of selected options, you should use `change` event, as Kevin commented on your question, to get selected option each time. And than append this node to side screen. Check quick example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('select[name="ice-cream"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);

let parent = document.getElementById('results')

function changeEventHandler(event) {
    // You can use “this” to refer to the selected element.
    if(!event.target.value) alert('Please Select One');
    else {
    let node = document.createElement("p");
   node.innerText = event.target.value
   parent.appendChild(node)
   
    } 
}
```

```html
<label>Choose an ice cream flavor:
    <select id="ice-cream" name="ice-cream">
        <option value="">Select One …</option>
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    </select>
</label>

<div id = 'results'>
</div>
```